# Any way to grab status updates from FB content provider?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm not even sure if facebook's content provider makes status updates, etc available to other apps, but I'm curious if there's a way some of the data from the facebook app. I'm fully expecting to be told that the only way to get the text myself is to connect to facebook through the api, etc, but just wanted to check.

To be clear, I just wanna be able to grab some updates from facebook as strings or whatever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to get Facebook status (and other user stuff) is via the APIs.

I have an app that collects user information / pics etc. via the GRAPH API (See the docs at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). For example you can get status updates for a user via https://graph.facebook.com/367501354973.

That's what the Facebook SDK example apps for Android do (see https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).